# I want an extra Legend in highcharts column chart

Tags: extjs, highcharts

I want an extra checkbox in legend area,so that I can select or deselect all legends on check or uncheck event using Extjs and **highcharts**.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: can u explain your question in details?

Comment: You can add a dummy series, enable checkbox for it in the legend and set a click event which will toggle other series' visibility. http://jsfiddle.net/1oe4fx30/

Comment: I got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkboxClick:function(e)
     {
           var series = this.chart.series;
           if(e.checked){
                for(i=0; i < series.length; i++) {
                     series[i].show();
                 }
           }
           else{
               for(i=0; i < series.length; i++) {
                 series[i].hide();
               }
           }

```
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anil_pin2/x5grrsc5/2/

This is what I want.an extra checkbox in my legend area.